# How to transfer a logo from InDesign to Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-indesign, logo, svg, gradient

I need to save a logo as an SVG file and asked the designer who made the logo for the vector graphics so I can save it myself, since he didn't know what a SVG is.

I was expecting a Illustrator file, since it isn't a "just text" logo instead I got a indd file. I can copy the text, but can't copy the symbols (colored with gradients) to Illustrator.

I'm at a loss how to transfer the logo with all it's elements into Illustrator without losing the vectors..

Is it common to creat entire logos inkluding symbols in InDesign?

Thanks for your help and input :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply export the file into a PDF and then open that PDF in Illustrator!

It should work fine and keep the vectors. You can use the highest quality presets but it shouldn't change anything anyway if it's really all vectors. Once you'll be in Illustrator, you can then export/save that logo the way you want.

Make sure you have your fonts opened too and make a "create outline" in Illustrator for your "final version".

It's not so common to create a logo in Indesign but it's still way better than creating it in Photoshop, and quite easy to convert.

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer! 

The PDF didn't keep the vectors when I opened it in illustrator (maybe I had to do something different?). It was like a picture (with a rectangle around the whole logo when I tried to klick on one of the vectors). 

But while exporting the PDF I saw that you can export as EPS and that did the trick! :)

Thanks for your help!

Comment: In some cases the opened PDF (in AI) will have a clipping mask. Just release it. Good to see the eps option is there too though